# Wait for key press but allow figure manipulation

Tags: matlab, figure

I had a search around and this seems to not be a well answered question that would come up a lot. Say you have the situation where you want to plot a figure, examine it and then press a keystroke to continue to the next figure. Usually for this Matlab would suggest `waitforbuttonpress`.

Here is a simple example if you want to test:

```
for i = 1:20
    data = rand(100, 3);
    plot3(data(:, 1), data(:, 2), data(:, 3), '.')
    waitforbuttonpress
end
```

**How can I wait for a keypress but still allow figure manipulation (ie. rotation, zooming etc)?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple but not so elegant answer is to use just pause:

```
h = figure;
for i = 1:20
    figure(h);
    data = rand(100, 3);
    plot3(data(:, 1), data(:, 2), data(:, 3), '.')
    pause
end
```

This achieves the desired affect.

Comment: I don't get the last statement "mouse use is not native like it normally is for figures". If you want to start with a certain [exploration tool](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_plots/ways-to-explore-graphical-data.html), you can just turn it on from code as well: `zoom on`, or `pan on`, `rotate3d on`, etc.. If the builtin interactions are not enough, you can also program you own by handling keyboard and mouse events (press, click, move, scroll, ...), and write [callbacks](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_plots/callback-properties-for-graphics-objects.html) for them.

Comment: @Amro, true, i dont know why i thought it started with those already. I will remove this from the answer. If you want to add a better answer that would be good.

Comment: Nothing to add, I think `pause` is the best way here to get the job done :)